# Give the general solution of the equation in $Ax=b$.

Tags: linear-algebra

So I have a problem that says, give the general solution of the equation $Ax=b$ in standard form, where
$$A= \begin{bmatrix} 2 &-1 \\ 2& 1\\ -1 &1 \end{bmatrix} ,\ \ \ \  b=\begin{bmatrix} -4\\ 0\\ 3 \end{bmatrix}.$$

When trying to solve this problem I have done the reduced echelon form...(steps below)
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c} 2 & -1& -4 \\ 2& 1& 0\\ -1& 1 & 3 \end{array}\right] \longrightarrow
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c} -1 & 1& 3 \\ 2& 1& 0\\ 2& -1 & -4 \end{array}\right] \longrightarrow\left[\begin{array}{cc|c} -1& 1& 3 \\ 0& 3& 6\\ 0& 1 & 2 \end{array}\right] \longrightarrow\left[\begin{array}{cc|c} -1 & 1& 3 \\ 0& 3& 6\\ 0& 0 & 0 \end{array}\right]\longrightarrow
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c} 1 & -1& -3 \\ 0& 1& 2\\ 0& 0 & 0 \end{array}\right] \longrightarrow
\left[\begin{array}{cc|c} 1 & 0& -1 \\ 0& 1& 2\\ 0& 0 & 0 \end{array}\right]$$

S0 $x_1=-1$ and $x_2=2$.

I'm just starting to work with echelon's and I want to make sure I'm understanding/doing things correctly, but I don't know where to go from here. How do I get the general solution from what I have found?

Comment: The unique solution is $(x_1,x_2) = (-1,2)$.  You're done.  Good job.